# how to port uclinux linux to any microcontroller

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, uclinux

I have stellaris LM4f232 evaluation borad. I have ported free rtos , sysbios to stellaris lm4f232 board and successfully developed an gps tracking application . But I always wanted  to port uc linux for my board . my question are

i) is there any material to port uclinux to any controller

ii)what are necessary knowledge I required to do the same

I have googled  a lot . I did n't get the right information, but I  have seen posts that  its difficult ,but  I cant  able to realise the same .any help????

iii) what is  the road map to achieve it  , what are the knowledge I should need to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

Linux, even uCLinux requires considerable memory resources; you'd want to start with at least 2Mb for the boot device and 16Mb of RAM (although a minimal system can be booted in as little as 4Mb).  On a microcontroller, this means that you must have external memory.

Another issue is that Cortex-M devices are optimised to run code from on-chip Flash memory, having separate buses for ROM and RAM so that data and instructions can be fetched simultaneously. uClinux must run from external RAM, which has a detrimental effect on the performance, and you will be unlikely to achieve the 1.25MIPS per MHz figure the CM4 is otherwise capable of.  It is possible to arrange for time critical code to be placed in on-chip flash is necessary, but it is of course a limited resource.

Some good advice on the issues of deploying Linux on a Cortex-M device can be found [here](http://electronicdesign.com/embedded/practical-advice-running-uclinux-cortex-m3m4)

Comment: thanks for your reply clifford. I couldn’t understood what boot device means

Comment: @tamil_innov: The "boot device" is the storage device used to hold the Linux image that will be loaded into RAM.  It may be NOR Flash, NAND Flash, SPI Flash, SD Card, USB memory stick, or any I/O interface that is supported by a particular Cortex-M3/M4 device, it is also possible to load a bootable image from a network in which case no dedicated storage device is required on the Cortex-M3/M4 target.  All this is explained in the link I included.  Either way booting Linux requires a bootloader to perform the loading of the image to RAM - the bootloader at least can normally run from on-chip ROM

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look on buildroot which as far as I know can be build for this board.

Answer (score 0):

adding to @Clifford , you can use u-boot (bootloader) ,already configured for many boards ,if your board is not on list you can edit it.,